# Unable to set width of 0 for a button contains input group

Tags: css

I am working on this demo. I am not sure why I not able to set the width of `#input-box` to `0`. I am trying to hide this container and animate the width of that to required size as it is requested but I  can not properly set the width to `0`

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
#input-box{
      width:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="input-box">
  <div class="input-group m-0">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">Zip Zode</span>
  </div>
</div>
  
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```

Comment: at first blush, it looks like the browser has a default padding for the button; which is what's preventing it from going down to 0 in width (the padding is still visible).  Try `#input-box{ width:0px; padding: auto 0px; }`

Comment: Before going any further you need to read up on syntax, as e.g. a `button` can't, and is not meant to have any other content than _phrasing content_, which a `div` isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set the following CSS properties:

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

#input-box {
  width: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="input-box">
  <div class="input-group m-0">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">Zip Zode</span>
  </div>
</div>
  
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding of button

```
#input-box{
  width:0px;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you would like it to look like?[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoMKp.png)

If so, you need to specify some other css properties:

```
 #input-box{
      width:0px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
}
```